# Wrap first character of a string using sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

Say I have a string `foobar`
How can I easily produce something like `[f]oobar` without specifically replacing `f` with `[f]`?

Use case: I accept user input of a process name, and I want to show the process details while eliminating the `grep`.

Comment: Does your system have `pgrep`? if it does, there's probably no need to re-invent that particular wheel

Comment: along with ps -fu $user

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do:

```
sed 's/^./[&]/'
```

- `^.` matches the first character of line
- In the replacement, `&` is expanded to the match, we are enclosing the match with `[]`

**Example:**

```
% sed 's/^./[&]/' <<<'foobar'
[f]oobar
```

Comment: great. what is `&` in this sed?

Comment: Nice.  Much more concise than ` sed 's/^\(.\)\(.*\)/\[\1\]\2/'`

Comment: @Moshe The explanation is given already...

Comment: @heemayl Yes I see now. Thanks kind strangers

Comment: @TimKennedy if you like short, `s/./[&]/` also works since `sed` substitutes only once per line by default.

Answer (score 2):

In just Bash, with substring expansion:

```
$ pat=foobar
$ echo "[${pat:0:1}]${pat:1}"
[f]oobar
```

Answer (score 2):

```
v=foobar
echo "[${v%${v#?}}]${v#?}"
[f]oobar
```